# Using rails to update the html in a redbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app that uses redbox to get user input.  I am trying to add in select boxes that will be dynamically updated depending on the choices made.  Here is the view with the select boxes which is called by a link_to_remote_redbox link:

```
<div id="select_div">
<%= select_tag "group_select", options_for_select(GROUP_LIST), :onchange =>     remote_function(:url => {:controller => 'webs', :action => 'update_group'}, :with =>   "'group='+value") %>
<div id="name" style="display:none"><%= select_tag "select", options_for_select(params[:group], default) %></div> 
</div>
```

The controller's method:

```
def update_group
group = params[:group]
case group
when "ONE"
  group = GROUP_ONE
when "TWO"
  group = GROUP_TWO
when "THREE"
  group = GROUP_THREE
end

render :update do |page|
page.replace_html 'name', "style=\"display:inline\"", :object => group
end
end
```

Through testing I was able to see that the update_group method is being called when the first select is changed and it sends the correct group that should be displayed in the second select box.  For some reason I can't get the replace_html function to make the correct replacement and display the second select tag.

Has anyone done anything like this or have suggestions on other ways to try?

Comment: You are using old `JavascriptHelper` methods for Prototype. Is your application using Prototype or jQuery?

Comment: I believe I am using prototype, what can I look at to be sure?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out.  You asking about prototype vs jquery sent me down the path and I found I was using the replace_html method incorrectly.  Instead of trying to have the div be hidden and appear when the first select was changed I changed it so that it loads the select tags needed.  This now works and the select box is changed properly depending on what is selected in the first select.